# JavaFX chart: proper way to switch series data

Tags: javafx-8

We have a java program that takes a CSV file and processes it into multiple sets of data. The data is displayed one at a time on an XYChart with a ComboBox to choose between them. However we keep running into problems updating / changing the data:

First we had a bunch of ObservableList objects for each data series, e.g.

```
ObservableList<XYChart.Data<T,V>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

and whenever the ChoiceBox selection was changed we would clear the series and add the one corresponding to the different selection, e.g.

```
theChart.getData().clear();
theChart.getData().add(new XYChart.Series<T,V>(data));
```

However, we would get errors when `data` was updated saying something about same data added to multiple charts. I think this would occur if `theChart.getData().add(new XYChart.Series<T,V>(data));` had been called twice for the same `data` beforehand.

So I wrapped it up like

```
XYChart.Series<T,V> series = new XYChart.Series<>(data);
```

and changed the chart data like:

```
theChart.getData().clear();
theChart.getData().add(series);
```

Works fine on my computer but on another when `data` is cleared and then `add`ed to we get a null pointer exception during the `series` `onChanged` event, which suggests some kind of race condition.

Questions:

- What is the proper what to change the series that a JavaFX chart is displaying?
- Is there a way to 'pause' onChanged events so that an entire data series can be updated before the chart tries to redraw.

Comment: Are you creating your own thread at all or are you just using the application thread provided by the JavaFX system at all times?  Are you mixing JavaFX and Swing or is it a pure JavaFX application?  Can you provide an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which replicates your issue?  What version of JavaFX and OS are you using?  Are all machines using exactly the same JavaFX version and running the same OS?

Comment: please provide a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @jewelsea  1. Updating the chart is called from another thread using Platform.runLater  2. Pure JavaFX  3. I will try to create a mcve  4. javafx.runtime.version=8.0.20,  OS = OS X 10.10, java version=build 1.8.0_20-b26  5. Should be the same java version, machine with error is an older version of OS X.

Comment: I'll have to wait until Monday to create the mcve as the other computer is at work, but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do a `clear()`, that will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. The proper way to update the chart is setting a new empty `ObservableList` and then add the new `XYChart.Series` with the proper `XYChart.Data` objects into.

```
chart.setData(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
XYChart.Series<T, V> series = new XYChart.Series<T, V>();
XYChart.Data<T, V> data = new XYChart.Data<T, V>(t_type_Value, v_type_Value);

series.getData().add(data);

chart.getData().add(series);
```